# SQL запросы в PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

```
$id=1;
$sql = mysql_query("select * from `table` where id=$id");
echo $sql[3];
```

Столбец под номером 3 есть (от лишних вопросов - считаю от нуля). id - ключевой столбец самый первый. Но не выводит, почему? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
echo $row[3];`